# iOS using the index of a string to copy manual parts of a string

Tags: iphone, ios, string, parsing, indexing

```
NSString *mainString =
@"COLOUMN1:Shaddy Van Dust COLOUMN2:245876 COLOUMN3:Info 3\nCOLOUMN1:Da Dirk COLOUMN2:45678 COLOUMN3:xcode\n";
```

This is an example of the NSString i want to parse.
My real string has around 31 lines.
Each information has the pre-fix "COLOUMNx" like before "Shady Van Dust".
(It's everytime COLOUMN1, COLOUMN2 & COLOUMN3, but each information after is everytime different and has a different length.)
Each line ends with '\n'.
The last token in my string is '\n'. (apart from '\0')
(With which token each line and my string generally ends doesn't matter, if this makes it easier.)

Now, i want to copy each information between COLOUMN1, COLOUMN2 & COLOUMN3 into a temp string to work with it.
That i want to repeat till the end of my string is reached.

I already tried methods like rangeOfString, but COLOUMN1, *2 & *3 exists in each line - in the same string.

What do i have to do?..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using :

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfStrings = [mainString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Which will give you an NSStrings array like this :

> 0 -> COLOUMN1:Shaddy Van Dust COLOUMN2:245876 COLOUMN3:Info 3
>
> 1 -> COLOUMN1:Da Dirk COLOUMN2:45678 COLOUMN3:xcode
>
> 2 -> [...]

The array contains NSStrings, which you can access with `[arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:index];`.

I'm not really sure what you can do with that, but I think you're getting closer to having the separate strings you wanted...

Hope it helps !

**EDIT :**

You can go further with that. Initiate a loop going through your array.

Get the string of index `i` :

```
NSString *stringToEdit = [arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex: i];
```

Divide your string into another array :

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfLine = [stringToEdit componentsSeparatedByString:@"COLOUMN"];
```

You now have an new array :

> [@"", @"1:Shaddy Van Dust ", @"2:245876 ", @"3:Info 3"]

Please note the empty string at the beginning, due to the fact that the string you divide starts with your separator, and the space at the end of the second and third string.

Now access this array again, and you will be able to work on your strings !

Good luck !

Comment: Just to note, you don't need to allocate arrayOfStrings with a value before calling componentsSeperatedByString. You can remove the `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` and just change that to nil or do it all in one line like so: `NSMutableArray *arrayOfStrings = [mainString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];`

Comment: Yup, I saw that when I was editing my answer (I'm currently adding something). Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentsSeparatedByString:`. I'll explain a trivial way(there might be better ways of doing this):

First separate the string into an array of rows as:

```
NSArray* rowStrings = [mainString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Then again use it to separate the data into columns as:

```
NSArray* columnStrings = [[rowStrings objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" COLOUMN"];
```

You'll have to remove the `:` again  as `NSString* columnData = [[columnStrings componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:1];`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
NSString *mainString =
    @"COLOUMN1:Shaddy Van Dust COLOUMN2:245876 COLOUMN3:Info 3\nCOLOUMN1:Da Dirk COLOUMN2:45678 COLOUMN3:xcode\n";

    NSArray *strArray = [mainString componentsSeparatedByString:@"COLOUMN"];
    NSMutableDictionary *stringDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSInteger idx = 1;

    for (NSString *thisString in strArray) {
        if ([thisString length] > 2) {
            NSString *trimmedString = [thisString substringFromIndex:2];
            [stringDictionary setValue:[trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]
                                forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"String%d",idx]];
            idx++;

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"stringDictionary = %@", [stringDictionary description]);
```

Outputs:

```
2012-09-13 07:16:02.064 SO String Parsing[21203:f803] stringDictionary = {
    String1 = "Shaddy Van Dust ";
    String2 = "245876 ";
    String3 = "Info 3";
    String4 = "Da Dirk ";
    String5 = "45678 ";
    String6 = xcode;
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to keep the "\n", just don't do the trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Comment: Well, we gave leads, you gave a complete working solution, lol :)